# notifyItemChanged(int position) is updating only single item in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-cardview

This for loop is responsible for calling the below function from the onCreate() function

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemname.size(); i++) {  // here itemname contains list of names
        AlertSensor(itemname.get(i));
        }
```

---

---

In a cardview 3 cards are present. The below function is not working properly and is only updating the last of the 3 cards although both seem to be implementing the userAdapter.notifyItemChanged() in a similar way. Even if userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(id) is called with a specific position value that card is being updated but while in for iteration all the cards are not updating.

```
private void AlertSensor(final String item) 
    {
                 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  // Saving the values to the local sqlite database 
                        values.put(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.SEC_NAME_COL4, "1");
                        SecDB.update(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.TABLE_NAME2, values, "address='" + item + "'", null);
    
                        String query = "SELECT id FROM sec_table WHERE address='" + item + "'";
                        Cursor c1 = SecDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    
                        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
                            while (c1.moveToNext()) {
                                id = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("id"));
                            }
                            c1.close();
                        }
    
                        alert_position = id;
                        userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(id);
        }
```

Although the below volley function is called by passing parameters to the function AlertSensor() via for loop and is updating all the 3 cards properly. Why both the functions are not working similarly?

```
    private void AlertSensor(final String item) {   // The function notifying adapter class
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://plateau.com/device.php", new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                int id;
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {
                    if (ServerResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
                        values.put(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.SEC_NAME_COL4, "1");
                        SecDB.update(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.TABLE_NAME2, values, "address='" + item + "'", null);
    
                        String query = "SELECT id FROM sec_table WHERE address='" + item + "'";
                        Cursor c1 = SecDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    
                        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
                            while (c1.moveToNext()) {
                                id = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("id"));
                            }
                            c1.close();
                        }
    
                        alert_position = id;
                        userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(alert_position);
                    }
                }},
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                         // Toast.makeText(Security.this, "S1: "+volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("item", item);
                    return params;
                }};
    
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);   // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        }
```

Inside the Adapter class onBindViewHolder() method. This method's code is responsible for updating the cards of the cardview.

```
    if(position == Security.alert_position) {
                holder.state.setText("< Activity Detected >");
                holder.state.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                holder.cards.setBackgroundColor(0x33FF0000);
            }
```

Comment: The while loop doesn't have any validation when to stop the loop and will always return the id which at the bottom because that's when the while loop will finish executing.

Comment: @SatyarajMoily but the while loop is similar in both the AlertSensor() methods still why both are behaving differently? The second method is updating all 3 items but the first one is only updating the 3rd item.

Comment: `SecDB.update(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.TABLE_NAME2, values, "address='" + email + "'", null);` the first method is trying to update DB with address as `email`
but the second method it is `item`, does that have to do anything?

Comment: @SatyarajMoily Sorry apology that was a typo. It will be an 'item' everywhere.